# Why do I get an invalid operator definition here in FSharp: (~!)

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

```
type Parameter =
    | Fixed of double
    | Free of double ref
    with
    override m.ToString() = 
        match m with
        | Fixed v -> sprintf "%f" v
        | Free  v -> sprintf "$%f" v.Value
    static member (~!) m =
        match m with
        | Fixed v -> v
        | Free v -> !v
```

The operator I try to define `~!` causes the error but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204%28VS.100%29.aspx `!` is a valid prefix operator.

`(~+)` works ok

The specific error is

```
    Error FS1208: Invalid operator definition. 
    Prefix operator definitions must use a valid prefix operator name. 
    (FS1208) (SketchSolveFS)
```

Comment: I'm using the Mono f# compiler in latest Xamarin Studio if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(!)` is [*always* a valid prefix operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204%28VS.100%29.aspx#prefix) so you don't need to use the tilde (`~`) to designate it as a prefix operator.

Unfortunately, when I made that change to your code, I just get a new error message. A while back (sometime during F# 2.0, I think) I tried something similar and found that the F# compiler (both 2.0 and 3.0) contain a bug where certain prefix operators which are valid according to the F# language specification are apparently hard-coded into the compiler (probably either in the type inferencer or the member resolver) -- so effectively, they can't be overloaded. IIRC, this affects (at least) the `(!)`, `(~&)`, and `(~&&)` operators.

Here's your code with the change, along with an example usage (which is where the compiler emits the new error):

```
type Parameter =
    | Fixed of double
    | Free of double ref
with
    override m.ToString() = 
        match m with
        | Fixed v -> sprintf "%f" v
        | Free  v -> sprintf "$%f" !v
    static member (!) m =
        match m with
        | Fixed v -> v
        | Free v -> !v

let p = Free (ref System.Math.PI)
let value = !p    // Error is emitted for 'p'
```

Text of the error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    'a ref    but here has type    Parameter
```

Finally, you can work around the problem by overloading the `(!!)` operator instead of `(!)`.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I made the change you suggested and then got the new error. In the end I decided to go with the non cryptic .Val member getter to extract the value.